# How to set same size for label text of treemap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I have plot a treemap using the following code:

```
library(treemap)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot2::ggplot(G20, ggplot2::aes(area = gdp_mil_usd, fill = econ_classification,label = country), size = 4) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(grow = T, reflow = T, colour = "black", place = "centre", family = "STKaiti", size = 4)
```

Out:

[image]

Now I wonder if it's possible to set the label text with same size, I have added parameter `size = 4` in `ggplot()` and `geom_treemap_text()`, but it didn't works.

Anyone could help to deal with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The vignette has a section `# draw all labels at fixed fontsize, even if they don't fit`, where they use `fontsize.labels=10, lowerbound.cex.labels=1, force.print.labels=TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `grow=FALSE` in `geom_treemap_text`.

```
library(treemapify)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot2::ggplot(G20, ggplot2::aes(area = gdp_mil_usd, 
               fill = econ_classification, label = country)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(grow = F, reflow = T, colour = "black", 
                    place = "centre", family = "STKaiti", size = 14)
```

[image]